# pass value of a textbox from view to ActionResult using actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a text box in view and 2 action link in the same form. what I want to do this that when I click action links textbox value will get in ActionResult

```
Html.BeginForm("downloadpage","Finance"){
<div class="col-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txttitle" id="txtval" placeholder="E.g. PAK10NOV18" />
    @Html.TextBox("first_name")
</div>


@Html.ActionLink("Download Master File", "get_master_file");
@Html.ActionLink("Download IBFT File", "get_ibft_file");

}

backend

public ActionResult get_master_file(string txttitle)
{
return View();
}

public ActionResult get_ibft_file(string txttitle)
{
return View();
}
```

Comment: You can do it only to using javascript  or  multiple submit button

Comment: yes but some reasons i not do this with javascript

Comment: MVC render Html.ActionLink as a tag, and to change href you can only to start using js. or change Html.ActionLink to button and use multiple submit button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework/7111222#7111222

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jquery and an ajax call?

Have a button that when you click calls a javascript function. In here you can get the value of the input such as this:

```
var textvalue = $("#txtval").val();
```

Create a json such as this:

```
var json = '{txttitle: "' + textvalue  + '"}';
```

and call your controller such as this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'@Url.Action("//Function", "//Controller")',
    type:'POST',
    data: json,
    contentType:'Application/json',
    success:function(result){
        //Do nothing or do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Comment: yes but some kind of work i can't use ajax or javascript becasue that mehtods convert datatable to excel so browser stop working when i use ajax.

Comment: i want to hit server side not client side